# How to debug Rust code from Python debugger in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a Python code that makes a call to a Rust code inside it. I'm launching the Python debugger through Visual Studio Code and stepping into the Python function. However, I couldn't step into the Rust code to debug. Is there a way to debug the Rust code too?

My `launch.json` is as following:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'd wager the answer is no. But you might have luck asking how to run your rust program listening for a debugger on a specific port, and then connecting to it with a rust debugger in a separate VS Code window

Comment: Related: [How to enable mixed mode debugging in Visual Studio Code?](/q/63545186)